# Check fields contain data and that one is a number

Tags: javascript, forms

New to javascript but I am trying to check if three fields (1) contain some data and that (2) the third one contains any numbers. The third one is a telephone # field. I realize dashes would be involved. And that the form could validate if a user entered only one number or a number and some text. But I'm starting small. Any help would be great.

```
function validate(){
    if ((document.myForm.fname.value=="") || (document.myForm.lname.value=="") 
 || (document.myForm.telenumber.value=="")){
        alert("You must fill in all of the required fields!")
        return false
    }
    else
        return true
}


<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <label for="fname">First name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname"><BR>
    <label for="lname">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname"><BR>
    <label for="tele">Telephone number</label>
    <input type="text" id="tele" name="telenumber">

    <input type='submit' value='Submit' /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: regular expression for phone number- http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [**typeof**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) function to check if fname and lname are strings plus a **regular expression** to check if the phone number format is valid.

**Working code example:**

```js
(function(){
  
  function validate(e) {
  
    e.preventDefault();

    var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value,
        lname = document.getElementById('lname').value,
        phone = document.getElementById('tele').value;
      
     //regex example for phone number format
     var regex = new RegExp('^((([0-9]{3}))|([0-9]{3}))[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4}$');
     
    
    //Validation
  
    if(typeof fname === 'string' && typeof lname === 'string' && regex.test(phone))
      console.log('Ok. valid user data');
    else
      alert('Invalid user data!');
   
  } 

   
  // Event listner for form submission
  
  document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', validate);

})();
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
    <label for="fname">First name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname">
    <label for="lname">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname">
    <label for="tele">Telephone number</label>
    <input type="text" id="tele" name="telenumber">

    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

**Additional Note:**

I'm checking the form controls to be string with typeof for more code clarity, but it is redundant as the form control are always type string.

So if you want the validation condition can be just `if(regex.test(phone))`

Comment: The value of a form control is always a string, so *typeof* seems redundant.

Comment: @RobG yes it's correct. I added that just for more clarity but it is redundant. I'm editing my answer to include a note about that. thank you

Comment: Thanks. So since I'm a novice, there's no way to do this by appending something to the code I figured out and included here?

Comment: @fbid: I appreciate this help. When I drop this code into my page it doesn't seem to do anything. WIth my own code, I get alerts but with your code I get nothing. What am I doing wrong? I'm putting it between <script> tags at the bottom of the page just before the </body> tag.

Comment: @Chris putting the javascript code at the end of the page before body tag closing is correct. Without seeing your code it's really hard to figure out what is the problem, as you can see in the code I posted is working fine. Have you copied both HTML and JS?

Comment: @fbid I put it in Codepen (http://codepen.io/kiddigit/pen/zqJGyG). I am teaching myself so I am sure I missed something obvious. I understand your code, though I couldn't have written it. But at least I follow the logic, which was hugely helpful.

Comment: @Chris Now it should work, here you go: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPGJoq . I pasted all the javascript code in its specific section and I added an id to the form, in order to be selected from javascript. I finally removed the onsubmit attribute from the form, as I listen to that event from the javascript so I can prevent the form to be submitted without validating the fields. Hope that helps

Comment: @fbid This is awesome! Thanks. Two questions: The ID was necessary for what? And what does " e.preventDefault(); " do?

Comment: @Chris Assigning an id to the form is necessary in order to select it in the javascript code with `document.getElementById('myForm')` and with e.preventDefault() i prevent the default submit behaviour which is sending the form when you click the submit button. If you try to remove it you'll see when you click submit the page refreshes.